# Set plugin page as homepage

Tags: plugins, wp-admin, homepage

### **The Problem**

So I installed a plugin (iHomeFinder's Optima Express), and it works perfectly fine. The page it made is 
 [conradbowenrealestate.com/homes-for-sale-search](http://conradbowenrealestate.com/homes-for-sale-search/). However, this page isn't made in WordPress, it doesn't even exist to it. I want to make it the homepage, but since WordPress doesn't recognize it as a WP page, I can't set it as the homepage. **Note that when viewing the source code, the "page-id" is 0.**

### **What I've Tried**

I've tried using this code in the functions.php file, but it doesn't enact any change on the website:

```
$homepage = get_page('0');

if ( $homepage )
{
    update_option( 'page_on_front', $homepage->ID );
    update_option( 'show_on_front', 'page' );
}
```

It does work if I change the ID to one of the pages listed in my WP-Admin's "Pages" section. `get_page_by_title` doesn't work since again, that's for WP pages and this is invisible to WP.

I've also tried recreating the object on the plugin page by going to the source code and copy/pasting it to my homepage's code. While it does work and is functional, it is out of proportions (too much space between options).

### **My Question**

How can I get this search plugin on my homepage? I want the above mentioned plugin page to be what shows when you go to [conradbowenrealestate.com](http://conradbowenrealestate.com/).

### **Edit:**

I failed to mention that within the plugin settings, I am limited to: http://conradbowenrealestate.com/ [insert text here] /. If I leave it blank, it won't save.

Comment: I got a downvote already. Does this question not belong here or something?

Comment: Yeah someone should have commented why, but you have not specified what the plugin is you're using so there's really no way for us to help without that information

Comment: K I added the plugin

Comment: have you tried to simply add a 301 redirect from your homepage to that specific page?

Comment: It is hard to advise without reviewing what plugin is doing exactly. `page-id-0` instantly smelled like hackish to me, that’s clearly invalid singular context and probably shouldn’t happen.

Comment: Hey @Spencer4134 were you able to get this working?

Comment: @DigitalDesigner Nope. It screwed up my homepage.

Comment: @Rarst Note that all of my other plugin pages (from various plugins) don't even list their ID's in the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

### **Solution**

Go into the desired page's editor (In this case my static homepage) and click the "Visual" tab, and at the top there is a shortcode option for Optima Express that lets you put the search form on the page.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few  methods to accommplish this goal.

Easiest in my humble opinion is to do a HTACCESS Redirect such as

```
 Redirect 301 / http://conradbowenrealestate.com/homes-for-sale-search/
```

Another method would be to use the [wp_redirect](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/) function as shown in the codex add a new function and include a code snippet like the one below to your functions.php file.

```
 wp_safe_redirect( $url );
 wp_redirect( 'http://conradbowenrealestate.com/homes-for-sale-search/' );
```

The third option would be to use a plugin such as [Redirection](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/)
With this plugin you can address your 301 redirects right from within the WordPress dashboard.

Hope one of these solutions solve your issue. :)

Comment: Thanks! I'll test these the next time I'm in the office.

Comment: I am not too keen for using redirect for such. Literally it doesn't do what questions asks to do.

Comment: So, I tried it, and first off, it doesn't do what I need. I need the url of the page to be conradbowenrealestate.com and the page content to be conradbowenrealestate.com/homes-for-sale-search. I tried your methods, and all it did was redirect to conradbowenrealestate.com/homes-for-sale-search/homes-for-sale-search... (repeating about 12 times). It said it wasn't rediriecting properly. Now I have a bit of work to do to undo this.

Comment: Nevermind I'm able to undo it, it's just cached in my browser.

Comment: I did some research. You really should tell people to test the redirect with a 302 before they do a 301. Luckily I doubt anyone else was affected, and I just cleared my cache.